# REST api call working fine in Postman but bad request through Powershell

Tags: rest, powershell, postman

Ive been trying to implement an api call in a Powershell script and was testing it in Postman and was working fine, now I am trying to do it in powershell but it is receiving `"error":"bad request"`. The call requires the following parameters:

```
$Body = @{
'refresh_token' = 'xxx';
'acces_token' = 'xxx';
'expires' = 10000
} 
$Headers = @{
ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Authorization = "Basic xxx=="
}
$Uri = "www.site.com"
```

Im sending the request through powershell using the `Invoke-RestMethod` as follows:

`Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers -Body $Body`

However it is sending back `"error":"bad-request"` when it should be sending either the token json or an error message of `"error":"token not expired"`.
When I try it through postman it is working fine, I don't know where the error is.

How should I format the request for it to work?

Comment: If you're using WIndows you can try installing a local HTTP proxy like Fiddler (https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and use it to compare the HTTP requests being sent by both methods - that will at least tell you what's different between them and might give you a pointer toward the answer.

Comment: Are you sure it requires `acces_token` and not `access_token`?

Comment: @robdy Thanks! I cant believe thats the thing that was holding me back, ive been spinning this thing for days.